# code to display set of avaliable wifi(SSID) in python

Tags: python, wifi, cell

I've been working on python to display set of available wifi(SSID) but i'm getting error as " **Interface doesn't support scanning** "..
what am i supposed to do?

```
from wifi import Cell, Scheme
Cell.all('wlan0')
cell = Cell.all('wlan0')[0]
scheme = Scheme.for_cell('wlan0', 'home', cell, passkey)
scheme.save()
scheme.activate()

scheme = Scheme.find('wlan0', 'home')
scheme.activate()
```

[image: These are the error's,I've included all dependencies.python interpreter I've used is Python3.5]

Comment: In the question itself, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: what does "Interface doesn't support scanning " error means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ifconfig eth1 up

iwlist eth1 s

try with this, errors might get resolved.